# Python rpy2 error loading edgeR R-package, but it is installed and working in R

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, rpy2

I'm having trouble loading the R-package `edgeR` in Python using `rpy2`.

When I run:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

robjects.r('''
    library(edgeR)
''')
```

I get the following error:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Loading required package: limma

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/data/scratch/user/source/anaconda/lib/R/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so':
  /data/scratch/user/source/anaconda/lib/R/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘edgeR’

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "differential_expression.py", line 221, in <module>
    diff_expr_object.run_edgeR()
  File "differential_expression.py", line 127, in run_edgeR
    probs = call_edger(data, groups, sizes, genes)
  File "differential_expression.py", line 64, in call_edger
    ''')
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 321, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘edgeR’
```

The main problem being:

```
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘edgeR’
```

However, when I run the following:

```
R
> library(edgeR)
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_ZA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_ZA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_ZA.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_ZA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_ZA.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_ZA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_ZA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] edgeR_3.12.0 limma_3.26.9
>
```

I can see that `edgeR` is successfully installed and running in `R`. Why would it not be working in Python? I tried to load other packages from `rpy2` e.g. `library(tools)` which worked fine.

Comment: Check if this R install is the same anaconda install, something like 'which R' in the command line. If it's not you will need to install edgeR again, this time  in Anaconda's R (~anaconda/bin/R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution...

Since the versions of `R` and `r-base` that I'm using were installed using `conda`, installing `edgeR` though the same channels fixes the error.

Simply run:

`conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda bioconductor-edger`

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

```
UserWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/data/scratch/user/source/anaconda/lib/R/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so':
 /data/scratch/user/source/anaconda/lib/R/library/edgeR/libs/edgeR.so: undefined symbol: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
```

The C library for edgeR cannot be loaded. Do you have the details of how R and edgeR were installed ? (I can see that anaconda is involved).